# I can't find a CLR Empty Project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, clr

I tried reinstalling, modifying, but still no luck...

The other CLR options don't work and always give errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ylvf.png)

Comment: please upvote this because i waited 40 mins looking for this as a beginner in c++ gui ( btw i m in 2022 and all videos talk aboute old visual studio that has different way of doing things )

Answer (score 14):

I suggest you should check whether you have installered the C++/CLI support. Open the VS Installer window, you could click on "Individual Components", then scroll quite a ways down to get to the "Compilers, build tools, and runtimes" section. In there, you'll find a list of components for c++/cli support. You could choose the version you need to install.

[image]

For more details about create CLR empty projects, I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [How to: Create CLR Empty Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-create-clr-empty-projects?view=msvc-160)

Answer (score 1):

I had VS 2019 installed and was working on a 2019 solution with 2019 projects in VS 2022. I had to install CLR (CLI?) support for 2019 as well to get them to show up, even though I was running VS 2022

Answer (score 1):

Installing C++/CLI support for v142 build tools worked for me.

I additionally had to install the .NET Framework 4.7.2 SDK.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).